# warning: address of local variable 'buffer' returned

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm working on an Arduino project and I need to use HMC5883L sensor's libraries. The problem is that the libraries are kind old and my compiler is complaining about the 'return' from a function:

```
/home/leandro/arduino-1.6.1/libraries/HMC5883L/HMC5883L.cpp: In member function 'uint8_t* HMC5883L::Read(int, int)':
/home/leandro/arduino-1.6.1/libraries/HMC5883L/HMC5883L.cpp:124:11: warning: address of local variable 'buffer' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
uint8_t buffer[length];
```

The part of the code is:

HMC5883L.cpp

```
uint8_t* HMC5883L::Read(int address, int length)
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(HMC5883L_Address);
  Wire.write(address);
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.beginTransmission(HMC5883L_Address);
  Wire.requestFrom(HMC5883L_Address, length);

  uint8_t buffer[length]; // Here is line 124
  if(Wire.available() == length)
  {
      for(uint8_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
      {
          buffer[i] = Wire.read();
      }
  }
  Wire.endTransmission();

  return buffer;
}
```

HMC5883L.h:

```
#ifndef HMC5883L_h
#define HMC5883L_h

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>

#define HMC5883L_Address 0x1E
#define ConfigurationRegisterA 0x00
#define ConfigurationRegisterB 0x01
#define ModeRegister 0x02
#define DataRegisterBegin 0x03

#define Measurement_Continuous 0x00
#define Measurement_SingleShot 0x01
#define Measurement_Idle 0x03

#define ErrorCode_1 "Entered scale was not valid, valid gauss values are: 0.88, 1.3, 1.9, 2.5, 4.0, 4.7, 5.6, 8.1"
#define ErrorCode_1_Num 1

struct MagnetometerScaled
{
    float XAxis;
    float YAxis;
    float ZAxis;
};

struct MagnetometerRaw
{
    int XAxis;
    int YAxis;
    int ZAxis;
};

class HMC5883L
{
    public:
      HMC5883L();

      MagnetometerRaw ReadRawAxis();
      MagnetometerScaled ReadScaledAxis();

      int SetMeasurementMode(uint8_t mode);
      int SetScale(float gauss);

      const char* GetErrorText(int errorCode);

    protected:
      void Write(int address, int byte);
      uint8_t* Read(int address, int length);

    private:
      float m_Scale;
};
#endif
```

I tried few suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679558/warning-function-returns-address-of-local-variable-wreturn-local-addr), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743411/return-address-of-local-variable-in-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744264/returning-the-address-of-local-or-temporary-variable) without success. Maybe I just couldn't figure out on how to solve this issue using those suggestion.

**EDIT:** There was an typo on my code, just changed it.

Comment: I can't believe that this is really code which was provided in a library. `uint8_t *buffer[length];` is complete broken. First it is an array of pointers and not an array and it is allocated on the stack of the function and later returned which never works.

Comment: My mistake, I was performing some tests and I left this behind. I edited my post with the correct code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you declare buffer on the stack. If you want to return a dynamically allocated buffer, use malloc:

```
uint8_t *buffer = new uint8_t[length];
if (buffer == NULL) error_allocation;

// Make sure to de-allocate after you finish to use it
delete [] buffer;
```

Comment: Where's the `malloc` call in your example?

Comment: My mistake, I was performing some tests and I left this behind. I edited my post with the correct code.

Comment: How does your example prevent multiple allocations of the buffer?  Remember, the memory can't be deleted until after the function exits.

Comment: It is C++, so one must use `new` and `delete` keywords : https://arduino.land/FAQ/content/4/20/en/can-i-use-new-and-delete-with-arduino.html. And it does not prevent memory to be allocated twice, but it is up to the programmer to take care of this.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution 1**

Instead of

```
uint8_t buffer[length]; // Here is line 124
```

Use:

```
// Allocate memory from the heap.
uint8_t* buffer = new unit8_t[length];
```

Make sure to deallocate the memory in the calling function.

**Solution 2**

Expect the input to come from the calling function.

```
uint8_t* HMC5883L::Read(int address, int length, uint8_t buffer[])
```

Comment: There needs to be a check to verify there is only one allocation of the buffer inside the function.  Try calling the function 2 times and verify.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to modify the library files and declare the buffer as `static`.  The `static` keyword tells the compiler that the variable will live after the execution leaves the function.  Since it lives after exiting the function, the address will still be valid.